# Synchronize all active threads C and release them one by one?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, queue

Is there a way in C to make all threads in a C program, wait for the other active Threads and then release them in the order they came, like a **Queue of waiting threads**?

Answer (score 0):

I'll attempt to help by giving you some notes I took last semester...

Threads

GCC program -lpthread

```
#include <pthread.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

This initiates the class / scheduler and names it `mulo`

```
pthread_mutex_t mulo = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

This initiates a condition to stop and start executions of threads

```
pthread_cond_t  c = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Define the structs that will be threads

```
pthread_t t1, t2, t3;
pthread_t array[3];   // this is valid to set multiple variables
```

Define your scope / namespace

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mulo, NULL);
```

Create the Processes

```
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, printMessage, NULL);
```

or just..

```
fork();
```

Validating creation, thread ids have type pid_t (int)

```
pid_t  pid;
pid = fork();   // All child processes return 0.. if    error = -1
```

Locks (& unlock) a function so only one process can run it at a time

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mulo);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mulo);
```

For signaling the unlock

```
pthread_cond_signal(&c);
pthread_cond_wait(&c, &mulo);
```

All functions that use threading must be pointers to functions

```
void *printMessage() { …. } 
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, printMessage, NULL);
```

passing in values from the thread

```
pthread_create(&array[i], NULL, runCommand, (void *) &command);

void *inc_count(void *idp) {
    int passed_in_value = *((int *) idp);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

finish it off

```
pthread_join(t1,NULL);
pthread_join(t2,NULL);
```